# Ember data model arrays don't always have data

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, ember-data

First time building an Ember app and I'm having difficulty with my models not resolving.

I have a set of Course models, each of which has an array of User models (hasMany, with async: true).

When I load the page, I see all of the API requests are correct (i.e. the client is making requests for all of the users in the array), and when I log the course model (i.e. when I do `console.log(course)`), I see the data in the console. However, when I do something like `course.get('admins')`, the array is empty.

The Course is not the model of the controller that needs all of this information (could this be why this is happening?), so I put the 'course' controller in the `needs` array.

In the end it's something like this:

```
var course = this.get('controllers.course').get('model'); // this is OK, has data
var admins = course.get('admins'); // this is not OK, has no data!
```

Even when I try something like:

```
course.get('admins').then(function (admins) {
    console.log(admins);
});
```

There's still no data! What am I doing wrong?

Here's more of the relevant code:

```
var VideoDiscussionController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['course'],

    submitComment: function () {
        var user = this.get('session').get('currentUser'),
            admins = this.get('controllers.course').get('model').get('admins'), // this is empty!
            isAdmin = admins.isAny('id', user.get('id'));

        var video = this.get('model'),
            text = this.get('commentText'),
            seconds = this.player.getCurrentTime() : 0,
            comment = this.store.createRecord('comment', {
                video: video,
                text: text,
                seconds: seconds,
                author: user,
                isAdmin: isAdmin
            });

        // POST comment
        comment.save();

        // Clear textbox
        this.set('commentText', '');

        video.get('comments').pushObject(comment);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your model is something like this:

```
var CourseModel = DS.Model.extend({
  admins: DS.hasMany('user', {
    async: true
  })
});
```

then, if you get your course model instance and if you do:

```
course.get('admins')
```

that line should trigger the AJAX call asking for the users.

Have you checked if such a request is called?

If not, could you provide some more code so that we can help you?

Comment: The AJAX call is triggered (i.e. I see a GET request for /api/users/:userId) when the page that loads all of the courses is loaded. I'll be updating my original post with more code!

Comment: `course.get('admins') ` returns you the the Promise, so you have to use it with `.then(function(admins) {})`

Comment: maybe it's the response/serializer's fault? can you copy the json you're getting from the server + the serializer code if any?